# error using valueForKey in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Why do I get an error when I used `valueForKey`... I am using same trick like in `objectiveC` ...

In `ObjectiveC`, the code is

```
self.strSubscribe =[responseObject[@"subscribe"] valueForKey:@"subscribe_ids"];
```

In `Swift` , the code is

```
self.strSubscribe = responseObject["subscribe"].valueForKey["subscribe_ids"] as! String
```

I declare the variables like

```
var arraySubCategory : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
var strSubscribe:String!
```

And I tried to access the value from below response

```
 { 
     subscribe = 
            {
               "subscribe_ids" = "1,14";
            }

 }
```

**Edit**
It works using Amit and Eric's solution but now for following data

```
 { 
     data =     (
            {
        "subscribe_ids" = "1,14";
    }
    );
 }  

  let dictionary = responseObject["data"][0] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
  self.strSubscribe = dictionary["subscribe_ids"] as! String
```

OR//

```
 if let dic = responseObject["data"][0] as? [String:String], let ids = dic["subscribe_ids"] {
self.strSubscribe = ids  
}
```

but it gives me error:

> could not find member 'subscript'

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but I have found a question with a title similar to you problem. Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508044/swift-nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript

Comment: It seems as if you have to cast `responseObject["subscribe"]` to the correct type, before being able to access its `.valueForKey`

Comment: subscribe does not seem to be a String (as displayed in your response). Try casting it to [String:String] an run .valueForKey on this cast

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu ya it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift doesn't know the type of `responseObject["subscribe"]`, you have to help the compiler a bit; for example:

```
if let dic = responseObject["subscribe"] as? [String:String], let ids = dic["subscribe_ids"] {
    self.strSubscribe = ids  // "1,14"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It's still the same problem: the compiler doesn't know the type of `responseObject["data"]`, so when you try to access the subscript there's an error (because *you* know it's a dictionary inside the array, but the compiler doesn't).

One solution is to give the type to the compiler by declaring an array of dictionaries in the `if let` condition:

```
if let arr = responseObject["data"] as? [[String:String]], let ids = arr[0]["subscribe_ids"] {
    self.strSubscribe = ids  
}
```

Notice that it's `[[String:String]]` (array of dictionaries), not `[String:String]` (dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Write like this.

```
let dictionary = responseObject["subscribe"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
self.strSubscribe = dictionary["subscribe_ids"] as! String
```

Since `responseObject["subscribe"]` will give a AnyObject? output and AnyObject does not have any member called `valueForKey`.

Comment: valueForKey method is not there in Swift dictionary. You can not use this method.